# Adding Tags as an Editable field In TFS work item template

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs-workitem

In TFS 2102 Update 2 they have added tags for the work items by default these can be edited (added removed and view) via the web interface.

I would like to add them to the work item template so that tags can be edited in VS 2012. I have added the field to the form but it is not editable and does not have and editor other then a plan Text.

I have looked and can not find any example of this working. Is this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17595791/736079, short answer: no this is not possible right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a work item tag within Visual Studio 2013 IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088167/how-to-add-a-work-item-tag-within-visual-studio-2013-ide)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently only available through Web Access. The Team Foundation Server / Visual Studio Team is looking into adding this to other clients as well. The following [Visual Studio User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio?query=tagging) items with Product Team Comments hint towards it being released in the future:

- [Allow querying work items by 'Tag'](http://uservoice.com/a/WjFgh)
- [Import tags via excel](http://uservoice.com/a/KBkYZ)
- [work item Tag](http://uservoice.com/a/qp0G6)

### Update

This has been added in [Visual Studio 2013.2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/02/05/vs-tfs-2013-2-update-2-ctp-released.aspx)