# Display new work item tags from TFS 2012 Update 2 in TFS Client?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Work item tags were [introduced in TFS 2012 Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx) as a new feature for Team Web Access.

Is there a way, even a work around, so that the tags can be displayed/edited in the TFS Client?

Even if it was just a semicolon separated textbox would be sufficient.

Comment: This is coming, but right now there isn't.

Comment: Great! Is this referenced somewhere you can link to? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently only available through Web Access. The Team Foundation Server / Visual Studio Team is looking into adding this to other clients as well. The following [Visual Studio User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio?query=tagging) items with Product Team Comments hint towards it being released in the future:

- [Allow querying work items by 'Tag'](http://uservoice.com/a/WjFgh)
- [Import tags via excel](http://uservoice.com/a/KBkYZ)
- [work item Tag](http://uservoice.com/a/qp0G6)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rudimentary workaround. Add the following to your work item template.

```
<FORM>
  <Layout HideReadOnlyEmptyFields="true" HideControlBorders="true">
    <Group Margin="(4,0,0,0)">
      <Column PercentWidth="100">
...    
      <Control FieldName="System.Tags" Type="FieldControl" Label="Tags" LabelPosition="Left" />
...
      </Column>
    </Group>
  </Layout>
</FORM>
```

This will add a ***read-only*** field in the client and on the web as well (unfortunately).

Comment: It's important to note that setting HideReadOnlyEmptyFields to "True" will cause the read-only tags field to *not* appear in the client and web forms.